# php yii wrong mime type with CFileHelper::getMimeType

Tags: php, yii, xampp, mime-types

wanna check my uploaded images for right mime type:

```
 $user->image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($user, 'image');
```

in my Validation i check mime type with:

```
print_r(CFileHelper::getMimeType($this->image));
```

well, i uploaded a pdf and mime type was application/pdf.
i renamed the pdf to test.jpg, and mime type is now image/jpg which is a problem. i just wanna accept images.

i use the newest versions:
yii-1.1.12.b600af; XAMPP Windows 1.8.0; PHP Version 5.4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Yii by default defines mime type according to extension.

[You can see the code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/utils/CFileHelper.php#L222)

```
public static function getMimeType($file,$magicFile=null,$checkExtension=true){//code}
```

As you see `$checkExtension=true`.

You can try like that:

```
print_r(CFileHelper::getMimeType($this->image, null, false));
```

So It will not decide by extension.

For validation purpose:

```
class Item extends CActiveRecord
{
    public $image;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('image', 'file', 'mimeTypes'=>'image/gif, image/jpeg'),
        );
    }
}
```

Alway use existing things, do not try to re-create.

Comment: thats not correct. as you can see in the source code first checks if finfo_open exists, then use it. if not, use mime_content_type and the last one is to check it by extension. in my case it uses finfo_open.

Comment: sry, in my case it uses extension because i spotted Call to undefined function finfo_open() and Call to undefined function mime_content_type(). if u set false there as a third parameter it only returns NULL

Comment: It would solve all problem if you met this requirement: http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php. The you have finfo_open function which yii can use. php already meets, but pecl should be PECL fileinfo >= 0.1.0

Comment: finfo_open was deactivated... but now i get failed to open stream: No such file or directory. seems it cant check a file which wasnt uploaded yet...

Comment: Of course it fails if there is not file, then what kind of mime type can we have. Actually why do you need to know? for validation? If yes there are already validation built in for this purpose. If not then you upload the file and save it with CfileUploader then call getMimeType method.

Comment: yeah understand that. maybe im a lil paranoid, but what sence does it make to upload it first, check it if its evil, and if it is delete it? meanwhile it crashed my whole system if it was evil...so why should i check mime types?

Comment: That is why I asked, with yii there is built in validator, If it is not for validation then I assume that u have already file uploaded, then It makes sense. But If you do not have it yet but for validation then check my answer I am updating it.

Comment: yes its for validation, and the build in doesnt provide a blacklist option, thats why i try to build myself ;)

Comment: i used the file mimetypes validation at first, but it didnt work cause i hadnt installed the php method.... thats why i thought they created crap and tried to build it on my own. i want deny some file extensions as well. but file only provides a white list validation? the file mimetypes works now. THX alot dude!

Comment: Have a look the doc. it is really good: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFileValidator It defines also wrongMimeType, wrongType. CHeck it.

Comment: yeah funny thing is i watched it about 4h ago.... now its 4am and i think im not concentrated anymore :) thx alot again. have a nice day. cya

Answer (score 0):

PHP offers finfo_open() that actually tries to distill the mimetype from the content of the file. Use like so:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
$mediaFile->filemime = finfo_file($finfo, $fileName); 
    /* close connection */
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php

In my limited experience, finfo_open() works well.